# RigidBody2D not moving properly

Tags: unity, c#

### Description

I've seen some Unity tutorials and I'm trying to apply good practices to modularize the code. However, I'm running into some issues while trying to use `rigidBody2d.MovePosition()`.

I have two classes: `Player` (which defines rules and performs calculations) and `PlayerController` (uses computed data from `Player` to interact with Unity itself).

`Player.cs`

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Player
{
    public Vector2 MoveTowards(Vector2 currentPosition, Vector2 direction)
    {
        return currentPosition + direction * 2f;
    }
}
```

`PlayerController.cs`

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Player player;

    Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    Vector2 movementDirection = Vector2.zero;

    void Awake()
    {
        player = new Player();
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        movementDirection = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb2d.MovePosition(player.MoveTowards(rb2d.position, movementDirection) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

What happens visually is the player's sprite moves (just a tiny bit) towards the given direction and goes back to (x: 0, y: 0) as soon as I release the movement key.

**Player on Inspector:**
[image: Player on Inspector]

### What I tested

Inside `FixedUpdate`, it **does not work** when I use:

```csharp
rb2d.MovePosition(player.MoveTowards(rb2d.position, movementDirection) * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Inside `FixedUpdate`, it **does not work** when I use:

```csharp
Vector2 controllerNewPosition = rb2d.position + movementDirection * 2f;
rb2d.MovePosition(controllerNewPosition * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Inside `FixedUpdate`, it **works** when I use:

```csharp
rb2d.MovePosition(rb2d.position + movementDirection * 2f * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

### Questions

Maybe that is being caused by the operator `+` and not creating a new Vector2, instead mutating `rb2d.position`? While I'm not new to programming, I have no experience with C#, so I don't know the specifics of the syntax yet.

How could I use `player.MoveTowards` in this case?

## Edit

Feeling dumb. Right after publishing the question I realized the glaring mathematical priority issue. I've been debugging this for hours. I guess it happens to everyone.

Comment: It sounds like you found your mistake, where you put the multiplication by delta time in the wrong place. Want to post your solution as an Answer rather than an edit?